# starting an activity from preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, preferences

I'm trying to go to the settings screen found at -

```
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS
```

From an entry in my preferences activity but am having no luck. At the moment, pressing the entry just refreshes the same screen as I was on.

My preferences.xml looks like this:

```
<Preference
         android:title="@string/my_location_settings">
    <intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS">
    </intent>
 </Preference>
```

And my manifest entry looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Preferences">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What am I doing wrong?

logcat:

```
12-11 15:53:34.170: INFO/ActivityManager(173): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS cmp=com.my.app/.Preferences }
12-11 15:53:34.400: INFO/ActivityManager(173): Displayed activity com.my.app/.Preferences: 229 ms (total 229 ms)
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <activity android:name=".ViewActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyPageOneActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyPageTwoActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyPageThreeActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Preferences">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.my.app.PREFERENCES" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Preferences.java (
sorry about the lack of formatting):

```
  package com.my.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

and preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference 
    android:title="Address 1"
    android:key="customURLOne" 
    android:summary="Enter a new address for 1">
</EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference 
    android:title="Address 2"
    android:key="customURLTwo" 
    android:summary="Enter a new address for 2">
</EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference 
    android:title="Address 3"
    android:key="customURLThree" 
    android:summary="Enter a new address for 3">
</EditTextPreference>
 <Preference android:title="@string/my_location_settings">
    <intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS">
    </intent>
 </Preference>
```

Comment: What does the logcat say? Also, can you post the manifest entry for your main preferences page? The one that you keep getting back to?

Comment: That is the manifest entry for my main preferences page, the logcat:

Comment: 12-11 15:53:34.170: INFO/ActivityManager(173): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS cmp=com.my.app/.Preferences }
12-11 15:53:34.400: INFO/ActivityManager(173): Displayed activity com.my.app/.Preferences: 229 ms (total 229 ms)

Comment: I still don't see the manifest entry for the main page, only for the one you're trying to get to.

Comment: oh sorry, the one Im trying to get to is part of the android os, I also get to it using an alert box by using the statements:               Intent myLocationOptionsIntent = new Intent(
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
  startActivity(myLocationOptionsIntent);                This brings up the Locations & Security settings under the Android Settings list

Comment: I don't understand. Your preferences intent is saying ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS, so clearly you're trying to launch the activity ".Preferences".

Comment: Right, I think I'm getting confused. I want to bring up the settings list for Locations & security, the same one brought up by the code in the comment just above. The .Preferences activity launches fine, then I want to go to the Locations and Security settings from an entry in the list. This is where it returns to the same screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand - you may be unclear about what an intent-filter is.

Your manifest entry says:

```
<activity android:name=".Preferences">
```

This is the definition for your activity called [your package].Preferences.

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS" />
```

Preferences will be triggered whenever somebody starts an intent with ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS as the action name...

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

This is supposed to be the default option for that action.

```
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Obviously, you don't want to use an Android API action name for your activity (unless you're trying to provide an alternative to Android's built-in location source activity). Use a different action name for your main preferences screen, preferably something with your package name in it.

EDIT: Also, try using a PreferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/my_location_settings">
    <intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS">
    </intent>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Sounds good, your right, I was unclear about intent filters thank you. I'll give it a shot and see how it goes

Comment: I'm still not having any luck cause I feel I don't really know what I am doing. Are you saying I change the action name in the manifest and the preferences.xml file? If I do that, how will I start the desired location source activity?

Comment: No. Change the action name of your ".Preferences" activity. Keep everything else the same. If you still have problems, post the entire manifest file.

Comment: No love, I changed the action name in the manifest to - <action android:name="com.my.app.PREFERENCES" /> but no joy. Ill post the whole manifest and Preferences activity and preferences.xml in the OP

Comment: Ah, one more thing - your preference item needs to be a PreferenceScreen. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks you. I have to go now and will pick this up when I get back, thanks again.

Comment: I'm now getting:    12-11 20:25:41.294: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7458): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS }
 when implementing your instructions.

Comment: We're getting there. android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS is a static String in the Android API, and it is "android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS". Use that string instead.

Comment: So sweet!, it worked!! This is great, thank you so much EboMike There is no way I'd have known it was that string. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing works  for me so i did: (I think it is a bad idea but...)

1.Remove this filter from manifest

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

1. Make preference easier

```
<Preference android:key="simple_key"
        android:title="@string/title_simple_key">
    </Preference>
```

2. Add Clicklistener in your PreferenceFragment

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    findPreference("simple_key").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: I don't know why, but with the other method instead of the activity that I declare, it opened the preferences activity again, so this method worked for me (: