# Start Activity from preference screen (intent defined in xml file)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-preferences

In my preference file I go this

```
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Title" >
        <Preference android:title="title" >
    <intent android:action="com.my.package.MainActivity" 
            />
</Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

The activity is created in the manifest file , but I still get

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.my.package.MainActivity }
```

How can I start activity from preferences screen ?

Comment: Does your activity extend [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) ?

Comment: yes I do extend PreferenceActivity

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue but none of the solutions i searched on stackoverflow solved my activitynotfound Exception.

Here is the working solution i found from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/543114/Android/Mobile/Launching-Activity-Preferences):

```
    <PreferenceScreen  
                android:title="@string/title_intent_preference"  
                android:summary="@string/summary_intent_preference">  

            <intent android:action="your.action.string"/>  

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

set an intent filter in your activity inside manifest.xml

```
    <activity ...>  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="your.action.string"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

This isn't the right way to start an intent from xml. The `android:action` field isn't for the name of the activity you are trying to start; it describes an action for an intent-filter (such as `android.intent.action.VIEW` or `android.intent.action.EDIT`) that another activity can supply.

See this answer for the correct use of `<intent`>, android:action, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751306/582004

Make sure that in your AndroidManifest.xml, your activity contains an `<intent-filter`> with the `<action`> that you are requesting in your PreferenceActivity (in the answer referenced, this is `android.intent.action.VIEW`).

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
 <intent android:targetPackage="your.package"
 android:targetClass="your.package.yourMainClassName"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your manifest :

This is the definition for your activity called [your package].MainActivity.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="example.action.ACTION_MAIN_ACTIVITY" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also, try using a PreferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/my_location_settings">
    <intent android:action="example.action.ACTION_MAIN_ACTIVITY">
    </intent>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

for more details please see this link...
[starting an activity from preferences.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415241/starting-an-activity-from-preferences-xml)

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like this in your intent declaration inside the preference xml:

```
<intent android:targetPackage="abc.def.efg"
 android:targetClass="abc.def.efg.hig.yourClassName"/>
```

**Note:** `targetPackage` should be same as the `package` property declared inside the `manifest` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`. This is confusing sometimes, so read it again.

So equivalent `AndroidManifest.xml` would have declaration like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="abc.def.efg">
<application>
   ....
    <activity android:name=".hig.yourClassName"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity from preference screen, you can just modify your preference XML like

```
<Preference
    app:key="your_key"
    app:title="@string/title"
    app:summary="@string/summary">

    <intent
        android:targetPackage="your.package"
        android:targetClass="your.package.ActivityClass"/>
</Preference>
```

or, if you need passing action, just put your action string inside intent property like

```
<Preference
    app:key="your_key"
    app:title="@string/title"
    app:summary="@string/summary">

    <intent
        android:targetPackage="your.package"
        android:targetClass="your.package.ActivityClass"
        android:action="your.package.ACTION"/>
</Preference>
```