# Start activity from PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I'm trying to start an activity from a PreferenceScreen. 
I can see, using the debugger, that the onCreate method of the Activity gets called but unfortunately nothing is shown. Here is my code.

```
<PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen>
        <PreferenceCategory>
            ....
        </PreferenceCategory>    
    </PreferenceScreen>
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="title" android:key="key">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.package" android:targetClass="com.example.package.MyActivity"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

My manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.package.MyActivity" android:label="@string/title">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My Activity:

```
package com.example.package;
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity_layout);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you setting `setContentView(<layout_file>)` in `onCreate()`? If you are already doing that, then update your question with code for `onCreate()`

Comment: @Sagar I added the setContentVIew(<layout_file>) it was already in the activity

Comment: For PreferenceScreen you can use 'addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.myactivity_layout); ' method in place of setContentView(R.layout.myactivity_layout);
, though it is depricated for using directly in activity, still works.

Comment: you are missing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` in your intent filter

Comment: I think this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810393/start-activity-from-preference-screen-intent-defined-in-xml-file/16943447

Comment: @Sagar added that modification but didn't help

Comment: @AntonioLaMarra instead of `android.intent.action.VIEW` can you try to create your own action String: `com.example.package.StartMain`. update it in manifest as well as Preferences.

Comment: @Sagar unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: As @UdayRamjiyani suggested, I've tried also to remove targetPackage and targetClass, but also this didn't help

Comment: I've tried with this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#Intents and I'm able to launch the browser. I really don't get why MyActivity is called but nothing is shown